# Use Illustrator SVG 1.0 or 1.1 with three.js and d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, three.js

I have found the following resources concerning the more or less direct use of an
SVG exportet from Illustrator
to use for WebGl with three.js and d3.

[Extrude, or, make 2d SVG path into 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179510/extrude-or-make-2d-svg-path-into-3d/16208711#16208711)

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry

https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-06/05-extrude-svg.html

[Illustrator/SVG to JavaScript workflow? (A templating library?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835693/illustrator-svg-to-javascript-workflow-a-templating-library)

None of these resources would ultimately help to directly use an SVG from Illustrator with three.js and d3.

What I need is either:

- a method to directly use an SVG from Illustrator with three.js and d3
- a conversion method to convert the SVG (also multiple path groups) from the Illustrator-SVG format to something that is usable with three.js and d3.

Think of it as :  User uploads his svg logo and gets a 3D preview.

Manually re-formatting the Illustrator-SVG is not an option here, so I hope you can point me to a few useful resources to solve the incompatibilities.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

[You can convert .svg to .json](https://github.com/chrisfinch/svg-to-json).

After it's simple to use with Raphaël, Three.js or D3.js

[Converted files are simple to use.](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.add)

[Edit : More informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835693/illustrator-svg-to-javascript-workflow-a-templating-library?lq=1)
//jsfiddle.net/yprgsvk7/ -> JsFiddle exemple